# Average and comparative left join MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, average

I'm trying to fetch information from 2 different MySQL tables.

**The primary table is this one:**

[image: primary sql table]

**From this one I use the information to get the average rate from this:**

[image: rating sql table]

How can I write an SQL query that will get me the `average` rating by counting all the rows with `rating_house = house_id`, and sort it by highest rating and if equal ratings, the one with the most rates.

This is what I have come up with myself:

```
$sql = "SELECT l.location_address, "
            . "r.rating_structure+r.rating_inventory+r.rating_service/3 AS average "
            . "FROM houses h "
            . "LEFT JOIN rating r ON h.house_id = r.rating_house "
            . "LEFT JOIN location l ON h.house_address = l.location_id "
            . "WHERE h.house_deleted IS NULL SORT BY average DESC LIMIT 10";
$result = $db_connect->prepare($sql);
if($result->execute()){
    while($user_data = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        $user_data['location_address']."<br>";
    }
}
```

However I get no output?

Comment: Note that the keyword in MySQL (and every SQL dialect that I know of, including the ANSI standard) for ordering results is `ORDER BY`, not `SORT BY`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For performance use INNER JOINs instead of LEFT JOINs if you know that the related rows must exist.

```
SELECT l.location_address,
       (SUM(r.rating_structure)+SUM(r.rating_inventory)+SUM(r.rating_service))/3 AS average 
FROM houses h
INNER JOIN rating r ON h.house_id = r.rating_house
INNER JOIN location l ON h.house_address = l.location_id 
WHERE h.house_deleted IS NULL 
GROUP BY l.location_address
ORDER BY 2, 
         (SUM(r.rating_structure)+SUM(r.rating_inventory)+SUM(r.rating_service)) DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Is there a way to implement so that if no rating is given it will still display? But at the bottom

Comment: If no rating is stored as NULL, then the averages for them should return as NULL.  If that's not working, wrap r.rating_structure and the others in IFNULL(r.rating_structure, 0).  That way NULLs are averaged in as zeros and will show at the bottom.

Comment: Sweet, thanks :) Also, I could get it counting properly to split between when equal rates. Did you just update?

Comment: Correction Matt, all ratings are sett, however what if there are no entries of rating?

Answer (score 0):

Below query should return houses sorted by average ratings:

```
select h.house_id, (sum(hr.rating_structure) + sum(rating_inventory) + sum(rating_service))/3 as "average"
from house h left outer join house_rating hr on h.house_id = hr.rating_house
group by h.house_id
order by average
```